# Let $X$ be Poisson with parameter $\lambda$. Find the distribution and expectation of $X$, given that $X$ is odd.

Tags: probability

$$P(\{X=x\}|X \text{  is odd}) = \frac{P(\{X=x\}\cap X \text{  is odd})}{P( X \text{  is odd})}.$$

$$= \frac{\lambda^{2n+1} e^{-\lambda}/(2n+1)!}{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lambda^{2n+1} e^{-\lambda}/(2n+1)!} $$

The denominator $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{2n+1} e^{-\lambda}}{(2n+1)!} $$
$$=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{\lambda^{2n+1} }{(2n+1)!} $$

Here I am stuck from moving onward

Comment: Clearly you can cancel the $e^{-\lambda}$. I would guess the expectation would be just above $1$ for $\lambda$ close to $0$ and just above $\lambda$ for large $\lambda$

Comment: [Apparently](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2068051/poisson-distribution-px-n-x-is-odd) the expectation is $\frac{\lambda}{\tanh(\lambda)}$